# Kerberos kinit with keytab not working with certain encryption methods -- PER USER

Tags: kerberos

I have two users, say `userA` and `userB`.  `userA` can use a keytab with `aes` but not `rc4` and `userB` can use a keytab with `rc4` but not `aes`.

This is the snippet that makes the keytab, tests it, and puts it into place:

```
#!/bin/sh
PRINCIPAL="xxxxx"
# METHOD="rc4-hmac"
# METHOD="aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96"
METHOD="rc4-hmac-exp"
KEYTAB="/tmp/$PRINCIPAL.keytab.$METHOD"
PASSWORD='xxxxx'
set -x

umask 0007

KEYTAB_TMP=$(mktemp "/tmp/$KEYTAB.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")

function cleanup {
  rm -f "$KEYTAB_TMP"
} 
trap cleanup EXIT

expect << EOF
    set timeout 10
    spawn /usr/bin/ktutil
    expect {
       "ktutil: " { send "addent -password -p $PRINCIPAL@FOO.COM -k 1 -e $METHOD\r" }
       timeout { puts "Timeout waiting for ktutil prompt."; exit 1; }
    }  
    expect {
       -re "Password for \\\\S+: " { send "$PASSWORD\r" }
       timeout { puts "Timeout waiting for password prompt."; exit 1; }
    }  
    expect {
       "ktutil: " { send "wkt $KEYTAB_TMP\r" }
    }  
    expect {
       "ktutil: " { send "q\r" }
    }  
EOF 

chown "$PRINCIPAL":root "$KEYTAB_TMP"
chmod ug=rw,o= "$KEYTAB_TMP"

if [ -s "$KEYTAB_TMP" ]
then
   if /usr/bin/klist -e -k -t -K  "$KEYTAB_TMP"
   then
      if su "$PRINCIPAL" -c "env KRB5_TRACE=/tmp/krb5_trace.$PRINCIPAL.$METHOD /usr/bin/kinit $PRINCIPAL@FOO.COM -V -k -t $KEYTAB_TMP"
      the
         mv -f "$KEYTAB_TMP" "$KEYTAB"
      fi
   fi
fi
```

Here's the trace for userB using aes:

```
[28458] 1625700358.740403: Getting initial credentials for userB@FOO.COM
[28458] 1625700358.740404: Looked up etypes in keytab: aes256-cts
[28458] 1625700358.740406: Sending unauthenticated request
[28458] 1625700358.740407: Sending request (185 bytes) to FOO.COM
[28458] 1625700358.740408: Initiating TCP connection to stream 10.128.65.6:88
[28458] 1625700358.740409: Sending TCP request to stream 10.128.65.6:88
[28458] 1625700358.740410: Received answer (185 bytes) from stream 10.128.65.6:88
[28458] 1625700358.740411: Terminating TCP connection to stream 10.128.65.6:88
[28458] 1625700358.740412: Response was from master KDC
[28458] 1625700358.740413: Received error from KDC: -1765328359/Additional pre-authentication required
[28458] 1625700358.740416: Preauthenticating using KDC method data
[28458] 1625700358.740417: Processing preauth types: PA-PK-AS-REQ (16), PA-PK-AS-REP_OLD (15), PA-ETYPE-INFO2 (19), PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP (2)
[28458] 1625700358.740418: Selected etype info: etype rc4-hmac, salt "", params ""
[28458] 1625700358.740419: Retrieving userB@FOO.COM from FILE:/tmp/userB.keytab.aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96.a148ff3d6c5ccc05f4644a2cdab2b23d (vno 0, enctype rc4-hmac) with result: -1765328203/No key table entry found for userB@FOO.COM
[28458] 1625700358.740420: Preauth module encrypted_timestamp (2) (real) returned: -1765328203/No key table entry found for userB@FOO.COM
```

Here it is using rc4:

```
[28706] 1625700362.799792: Getting initial credentials for userB@FOO.COM
[28706] 1625700362.799793: Looked up etypes in keytab: rc4-hmac-exp
[28706] 1625700362.799795: Sending unauthenticated request
[28706] 1625700362.799796: Sending request (185 bytes) to FOO.COM
[28706] 1625700362.799797: Initiating TCP connection to stream 10.128.65.6:88
[28706] 1625700362.799798: Sending TCP request to stream 10.128.65.6:88
[28706] 1625700362.799799: Received answer (185 bytes) from stream 10.128.65.6:88
[28706] 1625700362.799800: Terminating TCP connection to stream 10.128.65.6:88
[28706] 1625700362.799801: Response was from master KDC
[28706] 1625700362.799802: Received error from KDC: -1765328359/Additional pre-authentication required
[28706] 1625700362.799805: Preauthenticating using KDC method data
[28706] 1625700362.799806: Processing preauth types: PA-PK-AS-REQ (16), PA-PK-AS-REP_OLD (15), PA-ETYPE-INFO2 (19), PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP (2)
[28706] 1625700362.799807: Selected etype info: etype rc4-hmac, salt "", params ""
[28706] 1625700362.799808: Retrieving userB@FOO.COM from FILE:/tmp/userB.keytab.rc4-hmac-exp.3ddbc476378a57f4a7f4dbb700af6316 (vno 0, enctype rc4-hmac) with result: 0/Success
[28706] 1625700362.799809: AS key obtained for encrypted timestamp: rc4-hmac/B9A0
[28706] 1625700362.799811: Encrypted timestamp (for 1625700362.799810): plain 301AA011180F32303231303730373233323630325AA10502030C3442, encrypted 88F8E7E775BC3B93D0F392D9967E061B36246899F942A33EC123103A531DB6D2FB580A3C96FA97E24A74A844A41B532506F54F4C
[28706] 1625700362.799812: Preauth module encrypted_timestamp (2) (real) returned: 0/Success
[28706] 1625700362.799813: Produced preauth for next request: PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP (2)
[28706] 1625700362.799814: Sending request (260 bytes) to FOO.COM
[28706] 1625700362.799815: Initiating TCP connection to stream 10.128.65.6:88
[28706] 1625700362.799816: Sending TCP request to stream 10.128.65.6:88
[28706] 1625700362.799817: Received answer (1774 bytes) from stream 10.128.65.6:88
[28706] 1625700362.799818: Terminating TCP connection to stream 10.128.65.6:88
[28706] 1625700362.799819: Response was from master KDC
[28706] 1625700362.799820: Salt derived from principal: FOO.COMuserB
[28706] 1625700362.799821: AS key determined by preauth: rc4-hmac/B9A0
[28706] 1625700362.799822: Decrypted AS reply; session key is: aes256-cts/F217
[28706] 1625700362.799823: FAST negotiation: unavailable
[28706] 1625700362.799824: Initializing KEYRING:persistent:207:207 with default princ userB@FOO.COM
[28706] 1625700362.799825: Storing userB@FOO.COM -> krbtgt/FOO.COM@FOO.COM in KEYRING:persistent:207:207
[28706] 1625700362.799826: Storing config in KEYRING:persistent:207:207 for krbtgt/FOO.COM@FOO.COM: pa_type: 2
[28706] 1625700362.799827: Storing userB@FOO.COM -> krb5_ccache_conf_data/pa_type/krbtgt\/FOO.COM\@FOO.COM@X-CACHECONF: in KEYRING:persistent:207:207
```

Here's a sample of the outputs of the script for userB:

```
+ expect
spawn /usr/bin/ktutil
ktutil:  addent -password -p userB@FOO.COM -k 1 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
Password for userB@FOO.COM: 
ktutil:  wkt /tmp/userB.keytab.aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96.873c0ce2947f8bd6caea07de0d1d02eb
ktutil:  + chown userB:root /tmp/userB.keytab.aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96.873c0ce2947f8bd6caea07de0d1d02eb
+ chmod ug=rw,o= /tmp/userB.keytab.aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96.873c0ce2947f8bd6caea07de0d1d02eb
+ '[' -s /tmp/userB.keytab.aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96.873c0ce2947f8bd6caea07de0d1d02eb ']'
+ /usr/bin/klist -e -k -t -K /tmp/userB.keytab.aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96.873c0ce2947f8bd6caea07de0d1d02eb
Keytab name: FILE:/tmp/userB.keytab.aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96.873c0ce2947f8bd6caea07de0d1d02eb
KVNO Timestamp           Principal
---- ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
   1 07/09/2021 10:24:05 userB@FOO.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)  (0xdecff4a27a46a16267567a080311195e4e33d29caf3c4a2b782d2ed53b580c14)
+ su userB -c 'env KRB5_TRACE=/tmp/krb5_trace.userB.aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 /usr/bin/kinit userB@FOO.COM -V -k -t /tmp/userB.keytab.aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96.873c0ce2947f8bd6caea07de0d1d02eb'
Using existing cache: persistent:207:207
Using principal: userB@FOO.COM
Using keytab: /tmp/userB.keytab.aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96.873c0ce2947f8bd6caea07de0d1d02eb
kinit: Pre-authentication failed: No key table entry found for userB@FOO.COM while getting initial credentials

+ expect
spawn /usr/bin/ktutil
ktutil:  addent -password -p userB@FOO.COM -k 1 -e rc4-hmac-exp
Password for userB@FOO.COM: 
ktutil:  wkt /tmp/userB.keytab.rc4-hmac-exp.0db811bfd7e10197146bcca944b942d9
ktutil:  + chown userB:root /tmp/userB.keytab.rc4-hmac-exp.0db811bfd7e10197146bcca944b942d9
+ chmod ug=rw,o= /tmp/userB.keytab.rc4-hmac-exp.0db811bfd7e10197146bcca944b942d9
+ '[' -s /tmp/userB.keytab.rc4-hmac-exp.0db811bfd7e10197146bcca944b942d9 ']'
+ /usr/bin/klist -e -k -t -K /tmp/userB.keytab.rc4-hmac-exp.0db811bfd7e10197146bcca944b942d9
Keytab name: FILE:/tmp/userB.keytab.rc4-hmac-exp.0db811bfd7e10197146bcca944b942d9
KVNO Timestamp           Principal
---- ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
   1 07/09/2021 10:24:30 userB@FOO.COM (arcfour-hmac-exp)  (0xd6ed7055f216ab755e1827f582b35e24)
+ su userB -c 'env KRB5_TRACE=/tmp/krb5_trace.userB.rc4-hmac-exp /usr/bin/kinit userB@FOO.COM -V -k -t /tmp/userB.keytab.rc4-hmac-exp.0db811bfd7e10197146bcca944b942d9'
Using existing cache: persistent:207:207
Using principal: userB@FOO.COM
Using keytab: /tmp/userB.keytab.rc4-hmac-exp.0db811bfd7e10197146bcca944b942d9
Authenticated to Kerberos v5
```

Note both traces have ..

```
Selected etype info: etype rc4-hmac, salt "", params ""X
```

But userA ends up having in both logs, which fail the OTHER way around:

```
Selected etype info: etype aes256-cts ...
```

I'm working with the kerberos admins -- it's AD.  The two users are in different OU's  -- can there be different policies based on OU?  Is there something I should have the admins look at?

Comment: Can you get trace logs of a _password-based_ kinit for those users? How long ago were those users' passwords changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-kile/6cfc7b50-11ed-4b4d-846d-6f08f0812919) will likely differ between the two users.

Get a monospaced font, an flip the bits you want with the documentation in the link above. (AD represents this as decimal via its LDAP interface.)

```
000000000000IHGF00000000000EDCBA  Bit Flag Guide
00000000000000000000000000011000  24 (Decimal) is what you should want for AES only.
00000000000000010000000000011000  65560 (Decimal) is AES only with FAST.
```

---

In OpenLDAP this will look like:

```
$ ldapsearch -h example.com -b DC=example,DC=com,cn=username msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes
dn: CN=username,OU=Domain Users,DC=example,DC=com
msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes: 24
```

From `Active Directory Users and Computers` it should look like:
[[image: AD Dialog Box showing AES Kerberos Options]]

Comment: Is this field supposed to be visible when I look at the user in an ldap query?   Neither user has anything that looks like this field I think.

Comment: @rrauenza Depends on what you're using to query, but yes. I've added some output examples, both for OpenLDAP and also for `Active Directory Users and Computers`.